# oledbConnection.Open() yields Error E_FAIL(0x80004005) when attempting to connect to Informix db using DSN

Tags: asp.net, connection-string, informix

I'm trying to connect to an Informix database using an OledbConnection object, 
using VB in an ASP.NET script here's what my code looks like;

```
Dim oledbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=ifxoledbc;DSN=DWH;")
qry = "select location from dim_location"
Try
   oledbConnection.Open()  '<-- interpreter bails here
   'otherStuff
   oledbConnection.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
   Return ex.Message()
End Try
```

Everywhere else I looked the problem almost always occurs at the query, but this is obviously not the case for me, can someone please help

Answer (score -1):

Below is an easy syntax for creating an OLEDB connection on informix. You might want to change the code piece `New OleDbConnection("Provider=ifxoledbc;DSN=DWH;")` to match below

```
 Provider=any oledb provider name;OledbKey1=someValue;OledbKey2=someValue;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: this is merely a suggestion, you should put comments in the comment section, this comes nowhere near answering my question